# Deleting a row which has children in QTreeView

Tags: qt, qtreeview

I want to delete a row which has children from a `QTreeView`. I use `QAbstractItemModel`'s `removeRow ( int row, const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex() )` method，pass the row and parent index of the deleted row. But this method returns false.

How can I delete a row which has children? Do I need write a method to recursively delete rows?

Comment: Is QAbstractItemModel's removeRow method implemented?

Comment: Do you use your own model class or one of standard Qt classes? Which one?

Comment: If removeRow does something at all depends on the model implementation of removeRows(). The default impl does nothing and returns false.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late to the party, but I wanted to document this because I can't seem to find any good answer to the original question.

1. You need to implement `QAbstractItemModel::removeRows` in your model.  There is a Qt example, *Editable Tree Model*, that shows how this should be done.  The basic procedure is to call `beginRemoveRows`, delete the item(s), then call `endRemoveRows`.
2. Your tree item class should have a method for deleting a range of its child items.  You call this method on the parent item from within your reimplementation of `removeRows`.  The tree item class should be set up to delete its children when it is destroyed.  The Qt example does this through the destructor, though with C++11 and later this is best done by storing children in a container of smart pointers so they get automatically deleted when the container goes out of scope.
3. You do *not* need to account for child items being collapsed or expanded in the tree view - `QTreeView` knows whether or not child items are visible or not and will update the view accordingly.  In other words, if you delete a tree item with a few child items that were visible in the tree view, they will be automatically removed from the view.  This is something that I can't find documented anywhere, but from personal experience I can say that it works (as long as you call `beginRemoveRows` and `endRemoveRows` correctly).

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this: [removeRow](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#removeRow)

> This is a convenience function that calls removeRows(). The QAbstractItemModel implementation of removeRows() *does nothing*.

And here in `QAbstractItemModel::removeRows()`:

> The base class implementation does nothing and returns false.
>
> If you implement your own model, you can reimplement this function if you want to support removing. Alternatively, you can provide your own API for altering the data.